# Fatal parse error with address in profile

Tags: wordpress, error

I have an update your details profile which has started to throw a fatal error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /usr/local/php73/lib/php/HTTP/Request.php on line 412

When I remove the address fields it works as expected (I focused in on the address fields as it would save a phone number even when reporting the error)

I have checked the ConfigAndLog log but there is nothing recorded.  Looking further it is also happening on contribution pages.  I have tried different profiles but to no avail.

WordPress 5.4.2, CiviCRM 5.27.1, PHP Version 7.3.17

I am at a bit of a loss on what is happening here or how to rectify it - any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any custom extensions or modules?

Comment: Through a process of elimination enabling / disabling extensions I have narrowed it down to OpenStreetMap Geocoding (de.systopia.osm).  I have opened an issue, and kept the extension disabled.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I had the same issues. Disabling OpenStreetMap Geocoding makes it go away.